# How to share Image and text in Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

i want to Share Image and Text with Installed app in iPhone please help me i'm new in iPhone development. i don't know how to do this.

I Already complete in android with Below Code.

```
            Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(sharePath);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("image/png");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, s);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
```

But i don't know how to do in iPhone.

Comment: iOS doesn't speak Java, you need to port your program in objectve-c

Comment: i Know But i just give example how to do in android now i want to this feature in iphone

Comment: share on social network or email or sms . . . on what platform you want to share

Comment: Where do you exactly want to share this image and text? Text message, email, Facebook Twitter, Instagram, etc...

Answer (score 2):

You may use UIActivityViewController to share images or text.

Please go through [this](http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/) or [this](http://www.codingexplorer.com/add-sharing-to-your-app-via-uiactivityviewcontroller/) link.

Comment: The title says image and text not or. why everybody giving this solution while we can't share both on max social networks.